# Multi line placeholder text creates an indent in iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, cross-browser

The following minimal example looks right on all browsers, including macOS's Safari in responsive mode, except on iOS Safari.

```
<textarea placeholder="multi line place holder text in many lines" 
style="height: 50px;"></textarea>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/hyperknot/pen/NYYPXy)

On iOS Safari, in the first line an indentation is inserted silently. Does anyone know how to fix it?

iOS screen capture:

[image: ios screen capture]

iOS version: 11.2.6

Comment: Have you tried setting the padding ecplicitly? (just guessing)